# Saving user settings when using federated login

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I need to save settings for each user on my application.

I tried to use the user as a parent of my settings object, but I cannot do this since users do not have keys.
I then created an instance in my settings object that has a reference to user property, but in the docs it says UserProperty is unstable if the user changes their email address.
I then decided to save the user_id in a StringProperty() but if the user logs in with OpenId, the user_id element is None.

Is there a way to tie the user settings to the user object that works for both google accounts and open_id accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you add a wrapper class around the google account / open_id account, so you can use the parent relationship? Something like the following:

```
UserWrapper(db.Model):
  user = db.UserProperty()

UserSettings(db.Model):
  ...

# New User
user = users.get_current_user()
new_user_settings = UserSettings(...)
new_user_wrapper = UserWrapper(key=user.nickname(), 
                               parent=new_user_settings, 
                               user=user)

# Login Existing User
user = users.get_current_user()
user_wrapper = UserWrapper.get_by_key_name(user.nickname())
user_settings = user_wrapper.parent()
```

If the user wants to change their email address, look up the UserSettings with the old email, delete the associated UserWrapper, create a new UserWrapper for the new email address and associate with the old UserSettings.

Note I've made the UserSettings a parent of UserWrapper, in case associating multiple email addresses with the same account may be something of interest.